# Changing the 'Main Branch' in remote Git repository

Tags: git, github, branch, bitbucket, git-remote

We are using two remote repositories on Bitbucket for the same project- where one is the one with most developments taking place at this moment and more people having access to it. The other is just for our team and only the team members have access to it. Right now we are pulling only from the first repository and pushing to both of them.

Our issue with the second repository (push only) is: the `MAIN BRANCH` there (which I assume to be the active `HEAD`) currently set to some branch `'branch-x'` which is not the master branch. However, this branch was recently merged to the master and then removed from the other remote repo. But attempts to push this change to the second remote is failing with this message: `[remote rejected] branch-x (deletion of the current branch prohibited)`. The git command I used for this is: `git push origin --delete branch-x`

Is there any way I can move the remote `"main branch"` from branch-x to master and then delete the branch-x?

I also have a tag question: how can I change the name of a remote repo, such as change the name of the second repo from `origin` to `origin-2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this link](http://matthew-brett.github.io/pydagogue/gh_delete_master.html)  for deleting master on github, I would guess the process is similar for bitbucket.

To rename a remote use `git remote rename OLD NEW`

Comment: Thanks! The instructions in the link worked. 
- However, with the second answer, our both repositories have the same name 'origin'. (I know, not clever!) If we use the remote rename command, is it going to change both their names, or can I select one of them?

Comment: Remotes don't really have "names", they have URLs.  The name is just an alias stored in a your local repo's .git/config file for you to reference a particular remote.  You can't have to remotes in one repository with the same name, so I don't really understand your concern.

Comment: If the names are just aliases stored in my local repo, I'd like to call the two different URLs by two different names. In this case both of my repo's have the name 'origin' but I want to call one 'origin' and the other 'origin-2', and I want to keep pulling only from 'origin' and pushing to both of them.